# Integer input constraints

Tags: shell, arithmetic

I want to make an input constraint on `read`:

*Terminal Shell;*

```
read x
read y
echo $(($x+$y))
```

I want to make a constraint of `x`, I want `x` to be `-100 <= x <= 100`.
What's the command I insert before `read x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$x` is a string. A user may enter anything, it isn't necessarily a number. Input validation comes *after* input. You have to check if it is an integer, and then you can do arithmetic comparison. For instance

```
read x
#validate if it is an integer
[[ "$x" =~ -?[0-9]+ ]] || echo error
#validate range (this is better done algebraically, not with string manipulation)
(( x >= -100 && x <= 100 )) || echo error
# carry on
```

by the way, the arithmetic evaluation expression in `$(( ... ))` can use variable names, not variable expansions. Just write `$(( x + y ))`.

---

Solution for puritans:

```
x=$(awk '/^-?[0-9]+\s*$/{ if ($1<=100 && $1>=-100){ print; exit; } } { exit 1; }') || echo error
```

In this case, `awk` reads the input, not the shell, but you can also do it with `read` and then filter the result. Instead of `echo error`, you can use the expression in a loop (that re-prompts user for another input), or just bail out with `exit 1`.

Comment: This is only likely to work in a few shells, and does not use standard syntax.

Comment: What do you mean by standard syntax? Bourne-compatible shell? This one is clean, it works in bash, which probably covers more than 95% cases, and will probably work for OP. If it doesn't, we can further discuss uglier variants.

Comment: No, I mean standard - IEEE specified. According to POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this *before* `read x` - you haven't yet read it. How can you test the unknown? The only solution is to get the data, then test it. That, however, can be done:

```
case ${#x}${x##?*[!0-9]*} in 
(?|[!1-4]*|4[!-]*|1-*|?[!-0-9]*) ! :;;
(*) echo "$(( x + y ))";;esac
```

Comment: Can i declare $x first? (By declare i mean like c++ and python). So that i want the integer input to be in that range.. Anyway, i havent tried the ones you both suggested . Still away from home. Ill tell you if it works.

Comment: @FadhNhz - ahh - so you're asking about types? Well, in general, no. Some shells implement loose types - `ksh` and `zsh` and to even a lesser degree, `bash`. These are not reliable types - they will not suffice for input validation.